# apache: how to setup many virtual server on 1 IP?

Tags: apache-2.2

in my windows hosts I put

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 example.org
```

Then in my apache, I use:

```
 NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sites\example.com
    ServerName example.com
    <Directory C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sites\example.com>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sites\example.org
    ServerName example.org
    <Directory C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sites\example.org>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

that works great for example.com, but when accessing example.org, I got redirected to example.com

I tried with alias, but I got problems when accessing absolute path such as:

```
/css/site.css
```

Bceause I cannot declare documentRoot in alias.

Any idea on how to solve that (windows) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set the following since you are using `*:80`

```
 NameVirtualHost *:80
```

In your apache config and restart apache

Comment: yes: it has that  NameVirtualHost *:80

Answer (score 1):

Check that your `httpd.conf` file has the `NameVirtualHost *:80` directive.

Comment: yes: it is included !  NameVirtualHost *:80